# Getting args of Custom Validator control in ASP.net with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, validation, callback, customvalidator

So i have a  which i'm catching the event of it with the ClientValidationFunction.

The problem i'm having is, i'm doing some process with it and outcome of this process should determine whether the args.IsValid should be true or false. But the results i'm catching are in callback where i can't seem to find a way to acces args.

I've defined a var Args globaly and tried to get the value from there; couldn't get it.

I've tried to send it via userContext; no use (think it only accepts string).

I've tried to get the validator by document.getElementById, and i couldn't find the args property. This one is the one i'm most logical to me but i can't seem to find it.

The javascript code i wrote is as this;

```
function ValidateUserMail(oSrc, args) {
    var myField = document.getElementById('<%=RegisterUserWizardStep.ContentTemplateContainer.FindControl("Email").ClientID %>');
    PageMethods.IsMailAvailable(myField.value, OnSucceeded); 
}

//i need to edit args value from this function below.
function OnSucceeded(result, userContext, methodName) {
    if (methodName == "IsMailAvailable")
        if (!result) {
            var myValidator = document.getElementById('<%=RegisterUserWizardStep.ContentTemplateContainer.FindControl("UniqueEmailRequired").ClientID %>');
            myValidator.args = false; //doesn't work any ideas about the working property?
        }
}
```

and the code i wrote in aspx for validator is as this;

```
  <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="EmailRequired" runat="server" ControlToValidate="Email" 
  CssClass="failureNotification" ErrorMessage="E-mail is required." ToolTip="E-mail is required." 
  ValidationGroup="RegisterUserValidationGroup">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

  <asp:CustomValidator ID="UniqueEmailRequired" runat="server" ControlToValidate="Email"
  CssClass="failureNotification" ErrorMessage="Unique E-mail is required." ToolTip="Unique E-mail is required."
  ValidationGroup="RegisterUserValidationGroup" ClientValidationFunction="ValidateUserMail">*</asp:CustomValidator>
```

Thanks a lot!

---

Update; rendered html for uniqueEmailValidator Javascript in browser;

```
    var MainContent_RegisterUser_CreateUserStepContainer_UniqueEmailRequired = document.all ? document.all["MainContent_RegisterUser_CreateUserStepContainer_UniqueEmailRequired"] : document.getElementById("MainContent_RegisterUser_CreateUserStepContainer_UniqueEmailRequired");
    MainContent_RegisterUser_CreateUserStepContainer_UniqueEmailRequired.controltovalidate = "MainContent_RegisterUser_CreateUserStepContainer_Email";
    MainContent_RegisterUser_CreateUserStepContainer_UniqueEmailRequired.errormessage = "Unique E-mail is required.";
    MainContent_RegisterUser_CreateUserStepContainer_UniqueEmailRequired.validationGroup = "RegisterUserValidationGroup";
    MainContent_RegisterUser_CreateUserStepContainer_UniqueEmailRequired.evaluationfunction = "CustomValidatorEvaluateIsValid";
    MainContent_RegisterUser_CreateUserStepContainer_UniqueEmailRequired.clientvalidationfunction = "ValidateUserMail";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are two properties in args `Value` and `IsValid`

try

```
    myValidator.args.Value = '3434';
    myValidator.args.IsValid = true or false ;
```

Comment: Thank youu!! for your extremely fast answer, but i'm getting this error; Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unable to set value of the property 'Value': object is null or undefined (for the first line) and Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unable to set value of the property 'IsValid': object is null or undefined (for the second line)

Comment: are you getting this error in IE or in other browsers too.. try other broswer and could you post the rendered html

Comment: I'm sorry for the earlier comment, i rebuild the solution and i don't know why but it gives me the error: Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'ValidateUserMail' is undefined. Now i don't remember changing anything, but i'll focus on it. I tried it on the other browsers, since the debugger is not attached they didn't give me any error, but nothing happened either. I'm updating the answer with the rendered html. Again thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: thanks for the help i've looked up to the google vith args.isvalid thanks to you and found some article that might help and changed the code according to that! Thus i'm marking your answer. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function ValidateUserMail(oSrc, args) {
        var myField = document.getElementById('<%=RegisterUserWizardStep.ContentTemplateContainer.FindControl("Email").ClientID %>');
        PageMethods.IsMailAvailable(myField.value, function (result, userContext, methodName) { args.IsValid = result; });
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! My eyes sparkled when i first saw it, but it makes no difference since its still in function tag it doesn't see the args in the parent function.